# dynamically saving values of textbox and dropdownlist- winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have usercontrol in which I have  3 textboxes and 2 dropdownlists, when a user enters/changes the value in any of the textboxes or dropdown list I wanted to save the enetered/changed values to database directly.I don't have any Save/Add button on this user control. Please help with sample code I am a newbee to C#.

Comment: "Please help with sample code I am a newbee to C#.".....            Please provide US some sample code.

Comment: This seems like an ideal scenario for WPF and databinding.  You would bind the various textboxes and such to a property of a class.  Changes could be handled in the set method of the property every time they changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle each  `textbox/combobox` `Leave` event and update your database accordingly:

Sample code

```
    //attach your event handler to the event (if needed)
    this.textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Leave);
```

.

```
    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I have left textbox1, get my text
        var s = textBox1.Text;

        //db update
        var ctx = new mydbEntities();
        ctx.configTable.Where(x => x.id == 1).Single().Value = s;

        // commit changes to db
        ctx.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Comment: @prasy no problem welcome to SO, remember mark an answer as "accepted", if that helped you solving the problem. you can read more details here http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good idea and let me tell u why: lets imagine i choose something from your dropdownlist but i haven't type anything on any of the checkboxes, that selection will be saved to your database but with uncomplete information, unless of course, you make a validation on that checkbox that not empty fields are valid that way perhaps will help you.

Now lets think no matter what you do it, how? well you can create an event for thaT dropdownlist that will contain the querys or the functions to saved the data on your database.

This is the way i'll do it, but you may have another point of view! ;)

ps: i don't understand why they have downvoted your question, i think you are a junior developer (as i am) who is trying to do something and needs help.

Comment: My users wanted to save the values of dropdownlist or textbox when they enter or change the previous value regardless of any other controls. For suppose they have enetered a value in textbox , the text value needs to saved immediately.